# Is there any questions hide automatically when sort by votes?

Tags: support, search, sorting

When [sorting questions by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes), the last question at last page I see is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455660). But as I know, currently there are at least 2 questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068763) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734)) having lower score than that question. My question is, is there any criteria that hiding some questions automatically when sorting or searching? (Or they are hidden just because their score is lower than -100?)

Comment: The second one is locked for "historical significance", which hides questions from that list. But the first one isn't.

Comment: It is inconsistent when I try it.  Paginating a list that rapidly changes is not that easy.